# C++ Issue Trying to Initialize Application

Tags: c++

I am trying to execute my C++ program.  When I compile I get an error stating "Could not initialize the equivalent properties of Q*Application: no instance (yet) existing.  Here is the code for the main function.  Note, the program is taking four command line arguments which have also been set by default.

Any ideas what the problem is?

```
//  main.cpp
//  Homework 02
//  Author: 

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "complex.h"
#include "lodepng.h"
#include "rgb.h"


// struct for storing command line argument values
struct Arguments {
int width;
int height;
int color_depth;
int max_itr;
const char * filename;
double zoom;
double origin[2];
Complex c;
};


// Function prototypes
int julia_recursive( Complex & z, const Complex & c, int itr, int         

max_itr, const double radius2=4 );
int julia( Complex & z, const Complex & c, const int max_itr=256, const 

double radius2=4 );
unsigned int parse_args(int argc, const char * argv[], Arguments & args);

void print_usage();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

// parse command line arguments
Arguments args;
if ( !parse_args( argc, argv, args ) ) {
    print_usage();
    return 0;
}







return EXIT_SUCCESS;



unsigned char *img = new unsigned char[args.height*args.width*4]();

// TODO: Loop through all pixels in the image
for (int x =0;x<(args.height) ;x++  ) {

 //img[r] = new unsigned char*[args.width]();
    for (int y = 0; y<(args.width);y++) {

 //img[r][c] = new unsigned char[4]();

        // create a complex number for this specific pixel
        // by transforming coordinates to range [-1,1]

    //TODO: Calculate Real Value a
   double a = (1.5*(args.height-

   args.width)*0.5)/(0.5*args.zoom*args.width);
        //TODO: Calculate complex value  b
   double b = (args.width-args.height*0.5)/(0.5*args.zoom*args.height);
        Complex z(a,b);

    //TODO: Complete either the iterative version or recursive version

        // Calculate the escape time
        int esc_t = julia( z, args.c, args.max_itr );

        // recursive version
       // int esc_t = julia_recursive(z, args.c, 0, args.max_itr);

        // 1D array offset
        int offset = args.color_depth * (y * args.width + x);

        rgb color = color_map(esc_t, 0, args.max_itr);

        img[ offset + 0 ] = color.r * (esc_t % 256);
        img[ offset + 1 ] = color.g * (esc_t % 256);
        img[ offset + 2 ] = color.b * (esc_t % 256);
        img[ offset + 3 ] = 255;            
    }
   }

// write out PNG file
std::cout << "Writing fractal to " << args.filename << std::endl;
unsigned int error = lodepng::encode(args.filename, img, args.width, 
args.height);

if (error) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: Failed to save png to " << args.filename << 

std::endl;
}

delete [] img;

return 0;
}

// parse command line arguments and return a stuct of parameter values
unsigned int parse_args(int argc, const char * argv[], Arguments & args) {

// defaults
args.zoom = 1.0;
args.origin[0] = args.origin[1] = 0;
args.max_itr = 256;
args.color_depth = 4;                           // bytes per pixel
args.c = Complex(-0.7,0.27015);

//TODO: parse command line arguments
switch ( argc ) {
    //case 7:


    case 4:
        args.width = atoi(argv[1]);
  args.height = atoi(argv[2]);
 args.filename = argv[3];
        break;
    default:
        return 0;   // command line parsing failure
 }

return 1; // command line parsing success
 }







int julia( Complex & z, const Complex & c, const int max_itr, const 
double radius2 ) {



int iters = 0;
Complex zNew = z * z + c;
double zMag = zNew.magnitude2();
iters+=1;



while(iters<=max_itr && zMag < radius2 ){

zNew = zNew * zNew;
iters+=1;
zMag = zNew.magnitude2();
}

return iters;
}


 void print_usage()
 {
std::cerr << "Usage: " << "fractal <width> <height> <filename> <a> <b>";
std::cerr << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: If I was a psychic like you, dear Rasputin, I'd tell you. But since nobody is, we'll need to see some actual code.

Comment: ... wait, when you _compile_? Or when you _run_? That looks like a runtime error, but if it's really happening at compile time, we'll also need to know about your compiler and build system.